# Finding a Solution to a Equation that Ends up as a Weird Repeating Series

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions, recurrence-relations, diophantine-equations

I need to find the solution to this equation that ends up in a weird repeating series. The equation in question is:
$$
\ln(y)=\frac{K}{\alpha}+\frac {x^{2}}{2\alpha\sigma}+\frac{\ln(\ln(y))}{2\alpha}
$$

Another variation of the same problem is:
$$
\frac{y^{2\alpha}}{\ln(y)}=Ae^{x^2/\sigma}
$$

Note that those equal signs are supposed to be asymptotic expansions where $x\to\infty$. So if I end up getting a bunch of lower order terms that go slow enough (mainly slower than a constant), they can be thrown out.

Edit: I'm looking for the solution to be an asymptotic expansion for y~y(x) up to an order that's less than a constant. I also need y to be increasing very quickly. The answer has been found, but requires use of the -1 branch for the Product Log function.

Comment: I'm solving for y

Comment: I'm trying to solve for y(x) as an asymptotic expansion and don't know where to go from here. I'm basically stuck.

Comment: You end up getting some weird repeating stuff:
ln(y)=K/\alpha+x^{2}/(2\alpha\sigma)+1/(2\alpha)*ln(K/\alpha+x^{2}/(2\alpha\sigma)+1/(2\alpha)*ln(...)))

I need help in figuring out where to go from here.

Comment: Okay, where do I go from here? How do I figure out how different values of alpha affect the sum? And what kind of series is this? I've never ran into anything like this before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's look at the fixed point of $u\to a+b\log(u)$, so $$u=a+b\log u\\e^u=e^a u^{b}\\u^{-b}e^u=e^a\\ue^{-u/b}=e^{-a/b}\\-\frac{u}be^{-u/b}=-\frac1be^{-a/b}\\-\frac{u}b=W\left(-\frac{e^{-a/b}}b\right)\\u=-bW\left(-\frac{e^{-a/b}}b\right)$$
where $W$ is the [product logarithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_logarithm), which is only defined for $-e^{-a/b}/b\ge-1/e$ (and requires a branch cut on $(-1/e,0)$).

In our case, we have $\log(y)$ the fixed point of $u\to a+b\log(u)$ where $a=\frac{K}\alpha+\frac{x^2}{2\alpha\sigma}$ and $b=\frac1{2\alpha}$ so the above gives us $$\log(y)=-\frac1{2\alpha}W_0\left(-2\alpha e^{-2K-x^2/\sigma}\right)\\y(x)=\exp\left(-\frac1{2\alpha}W_0\left(-2\alpha e^{-2K-x^2/\sigma}\right)\right)$$

There's probably a way to clean this up, but eh.

Note that for large $x$ we have that $W_0(x)\sim \log(x)-\log(\log(x))$.

Comment: This works. The only thing is that we have to be careful of the branch in question. I needed the W_-1_(x) branch simply because I need y(x)-->infinity so ln(y)-->-infinity.

Answer (score 0):

For the first equation $$\ln(y)=\frac{K}{\alpha}+\frac {x^{2}}{2\alpha\sigma}+\frac{\ln(\ln(y))}{2\alpha}$$ let us define $y=e^z$ and $A=\frac{K}{\alpha}+\frac {x^{2}}{2\alpha\sigma}$. This transforms the equation to $$z=A+\frac{\log(z)}{2\alpha}$$ the solution of which being given in terms of [Lambert function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) $$z=-\frac{W\left(-2 \alpha  e^{-2 \alpha  A}\right)}{2 \alpha }$$ 
$$\log(y)=-\frac{W\left(-2 \alpha  e^{-(2 K+\frac{x^2}{\sigma })}\right)}{2 \alpha }$$ and $x$ is supposed to be very large. What you could use if that, for small values of $t$ $$W(t)=t-t^2+\frac{3 t^3}{2}+O\left(t^4\right)$$ So, limited to first order, $$\log(y)\approx  e^{-(2 K+\frac{x^2}{\sigma })}$$